# How to transport columns from one matrix to another matrix according to first column values

Tags: r

I have the following matrix:

```
1 a d
2 s c
4 d 0 
7 f t
```

I want to have the following:

```
1 a d
2 s c
3 0 0
4 d 0
5 0 0
6 0 0
7 f t
```

Moreover, I would like it to be done in a way where I would not have to specify each column...

Thank you,
G

Comment: Stack Overflow is NOT a "give me the code" site. Please tell us what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Also, your "matrix" contains `characters` and `numerics`. Perhaps it is a `data.frame` instead?

Comment: Yes, it is a data frame. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If `dat` is `data.frame` (It is better to store `mixed` class columns in data.frame than in matrix)

```
dat2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, ncol=ncol(dat), nrow=max(dat$V1)))
dat2$V1 <- 1:nrow(dat2)
dat2[dat2$V1 %in% dat$V1,-1] <- unlist(dat[,-1])
dat2
#  V1 V2 V3
#1  1  a  d
#2  2  s  c
#3  3  0  0
#4  4  d  0
#5  5  0  0
#6  6  0  0
#7  7  f  t
```

Or you could do

```
dat1 <- transform(dat[rep(1:nrow(dat),c(1,diff(dat$V1))),], V1=seq_along(V1))
dat1[duplicated(dat1[,-1], fromLast=TRUE),-1] <- 0
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 7L), V2 = c("a", "s", "d", 
"f"), V3 = c("d", "c", "0", "t")), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: @David Arenburg Oops, thanks for the notification. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Or use `merge`

```
df2 <- merge(data.frame(V1 = seq_len(max(df[, 1]))), df, by = "V1", all.x = TRUE) 
df2[is.na(df2)] <- 0
#   V1 V2 V3
# 1  1  a  d
# 2  2  s  c
# 3  3  0  0
# 4  4  d  0
# 5  5  0  0
# 6  6  0  0
# 7  7  f  t
```

Where `df` is

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 7L), V2 = c("a", "s", "d", 
"f"), V3 = c("d", "c", "0", "t")), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```